# Nullpointer is throwing in pom structure

Tags: selenium-webdriver, nullpointerexception

I am cereating 3class. 1 is base class where I initialise my chrome driver, 1is login page wher only login is doing, 1class is execution class. But its opening the url but after that null pointer exception coming

Comment: is your login class object correctly called once the chrome driver is getting initialised ?

Comment: How to check it? I am in New in selenium